# JdbcTemplate query close database connection

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbctemplate

I use jpa with hibernate. I have following method:

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod(){
...
firstJDBCTemplateQuery();
secondJDBCTemplateQuery();
...

}
```

`firstJDBCTemplateQuery` works, but it closes connection to database. When second `secondJDBCTempolateQuery` is executed

`java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed exception`

is thrown what causes

`org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction ...`

My configuration:
**EDIT**

```
     <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

        </bean>


        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />

        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.emisoft.ami.user.domain" />

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.emisoft.ami.user.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
        ...
```

I don't know why 'firstJDBCTemplateQuery' close db connection. How to resolve this problem?

**StackTrace:**

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:296)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:140)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:676)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:731)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:747)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:782)
        at org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager.findGroupId(JdbcUserDetailsManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager.addUserToGroup(JdbcUserDetailsManager.java:301)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////This is secondJDBCTemplateQuery///////////
        at com.emisoft.ami.user.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.insert(UserServiceImpl.java:42)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.insert(Unknown Source)
        at com.kulig.test.service.PaymentServiceContext.main(PaymentServiceContext.java:28)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.getMetaData(PoolingDataSource.java:244)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285)
        ... 29 more
    DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator - Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '0', will now try the fallback translator
    DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
    DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@76c741]
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - rolling back
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Could not toggle autocommit
    java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:327)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.releaseManagedConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:209)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:106)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:539)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:493)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:264)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.insert(Unknown Source)
        at com.kulig.test.service.PaymentServiceContext.main(PaymentServiceContext.java:28)
    DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@76c741] after transaction
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
    ERROR: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
    org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select id from groups where group_name = ?]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Connection is closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:676)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:731)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:747)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:782)
        at org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager.findGroupId(JdbcUserDetailsManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager.addUserToGroup(JdbcUserDetailsManager.java:301)
        at com.emisoft.ami.user.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.insert(UserServiceImpl.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.insert(Unknown Source)
        at com.kulig.test.service.PaymentServiceContext.main(PaymentServiceContext.java:28)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:312)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1446)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:583)
        ... 23 more
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:543)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:493)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:264)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.insert(Unknown Source)
        at com.kulig.test.service.PaymentServiceContext.main(PaymentServiceContext.java:28)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:109)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:539)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:215)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:106)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:209)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.rollback(PoolingDataSource.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
        ... 12 more
```

**EDIT**
I checked `secondJDBCTemplateQuery` in stacktrace.

**EDIT**

I use `org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager`

`firstJDBCTemplateQuery` is `createUser(UserDetails user)`

`secondJDBCTemplateQuery` is `addUserToGroup(String username, String groupName)`

```
public void createUser(final UserDetails user) {
        validateUserDetails(user);
        getJdbcTemplate().update(createUserSql, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                ps.setString(1, user.getUsername());
                ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
                ps.setBoolean(3, user.isEnabled());
            }

        });

        if (getEnableAuthorities()) {
            insertUserAuthorities(user);
        }
    }


public void addUserToGroup(final String username, final String groupName) {
        logger.debug("Adding user '" + username + "' to group '" + groupName + "'");
        Assert.hasText(username);
        Assert.hasText(groupName);

        final int id = findGroupId(groupName);
        getJdbcTemplate().update(insertGroupMemberSql, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                ps.setInt(1, id);
                ps.setString(2, username);
            }
        });

        userCache.removeUserFromCache(username);
    }
```

**EDIT DEBUG RESULT**:

Beigin transaction on startup `myMethod()`:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.emisoft.ami.user.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.insert]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@b18ac9] for JPA transaction
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@940dc4]
```

//////////////////////////////////
`firstJDBCTemplateMethod`:
//////////////////////////////////

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into users (username, password, enabled) values (?,?,?)]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
```

/////////////////////////////////////////
`secondJDBCTemplateMethod`:
////////////////////////////////////

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [select id from groups where group_name = ?]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - Looking up default SQLErrorCodes for DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@150f6f]
WARN : org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed. ///This is the beginning of stacktrace which is located above.
```

**EDIT**
`PaymentServiceContext` :

```
public class PaymentServiceContext {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "com/kulig/test/service/PaymentServiceTest-context.xml");

        UserService userService = context.getBean(UserService.class);
        ///CREATE POJO OBJECTS credentials and p
                ...
        userService.insert(credentials, p);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the fullstracktrace.

Comment: can you post `firstJDBCTemplateQuery` and `secondJDBCTemplateQuery` codes

Comment: At first sight nothing wrong with the configuration.Can you post the debug/trace information for the first transaction/surrounding method?

Comment: And the code for `PaymentServiceContext`.

Comment: I added. There is only call to `userService.insert(..)` method which I named `myMethod()` on the begining of my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a bug in hibernate. I changed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and it works.

Comment: upgrading spring should allow you to use hibernate 4.2 (see bellow)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I have had that same issue recently...

After debugging trough the Hibernate code, I noticed Hibernate 4 calls HibernateJpaDialect.releaseConnection at some point. Comments before suggest that it's only to release the connection, but not to close it since it's the connection used by the transactional context. However, that releaseConnection method does in fact call JdbcUtils.closeConnection(con). The HibernateJpaDialect class responsible is actually part of the spring framework, not hibernate.

In the end, this issue is reported by Spring as a bug (SPR-10395) and should be fixed in release 3.2.3 or above. So in the end, you can use Hibernate 4.2 but you'll have to upgrade spring (orm) in that case:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparison of 2 different version of HibernateJpaDialect from spring-orm artifact. 
Thanks to @Kevin Chabot for pointing this out:

**HibernateJpaDialect (spring-orm ver 3.1.4)**

```
public void releaseConnection(Connection con) {
    JdbcUtils.closeConnection(con);
}
```

**HibernateJpaDialect (spring-orm ver 3.2.8)**

```
public void releaseConnection(Connection con) {
    if (sessionConnectionMethod != null) {
        // Need to explicitly call close() with Hibernate 3.x in order to allow
        // for eager release of the underlying physical Connection if necessary.
        // However, do not do this on Hibernate 4.2+ since it would return the
        // physical Connection to the pool right away, making it unusable for
        // further operations within the current transaction!
        JdbcUtils.closeConnection(con);
    }
}
```

Switching to `spring-orm 3.2.3+` solves this problem. Be careful to include spring-orm in your pom.xml explicitly. The common mistake is when pom.xml contains only `spring-data` and fetches `spring-orm` thru transitive dependency from `spring-data` - and than it may be in wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you are using the same `DataSource` for JPA as for your `JdbcTemplate`. Next wire the `DataSource` to the `JpaTransactionManager`.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />        
</bean>
```

This will make the transaction managed by the same transaction manager (you should only have one transaction manage

Comment: I think that `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` finds dataSource automatically. I have only one dataSource so there should not be a problem.

Comment: I did as you said and nothing has changed

Comment: It will be detected only if that is the same datasource used by the EntityManager. Can you update your question with your full configuration (`persistence.xml` and `EntityManagerFactory` configuration).

Comment: I added `EntityManagerFactory`. Instead of `persistence.xml` I use `packagesToScan` property in `EntityManagerFactory`.