# C3P0Connection properties

Tags: java, spring, c3p0

Following is the my configuration file for `C3p0` connection pool. But after some time on starting my application all the connections are reaching to max connections i.e 200 and sitting in idle after that there are no connections are being used by application and if I hit my application URL from browser it is says that service temp unavailable.

My application is client-socket connection application, on opening the connection from client I am doing the data insertions and updations on DB.

```
<bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname" />
        <property name="user" value="developer" />
        <property name="password" value="developerPassword" />
        <!-- <property name="initialPoolSize" value="20"/> -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1" />
        <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="900" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="2" />
        <!-- <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="300"/> -->
        <!-- <property name="maxStatements" value="500"/> -->
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="60" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="1000" />
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: That behavior has nothing to do with C3P0 configuration, but with the connection leak your code exhibits.

Comment: Are you not closing the connections. As my knowledge once you close the connection from java code then the connection returns to the pool.

Comment: I am using the Jdbc template and dao classes to do the database transactions how can i close the jdbctemplate connections.Ex:jdbcTemplate.update(sql, args);

Comment: If you are using Jdbc template then it will automatically do the work for you. Then I am not sure regarding your issue. Just a pointer you can check the below link if you get any help there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001813/jdbctemplate-query-close-database-connection

Comment: Judging from the xml you use spring and in general when you don't have proper transaction management setup your connection will leak. Post some of the dao/repository code.

Comment: you may well have a Connection leak. you have some pretty terrible settings: maxIdleTime of 1 and maxIdleTimeExcessConnections of 2 are pathological. if you do have a leak, you should see stack traces of the code that checked out the unreturned Connections in your logs.

Comment: But there are no unreturned Connections logs in my application log file.Is that log file is different from application log file??